# How to migrate to a new Mac, including SSH keys and dotfiles?

Tags: homebrew, migration

I have an up-to-date 2018 MacBook Pro that I am replacing with a different 2018 MacBook Pro. I'd like to migrate all the content from the first one to the new one, including the SSH keys, all the dotfiles (`.gitconfig`, `.zshrc` etc.), PostgreSQL databases, Homebrew-installed packages, and the system and application preferences.

Does macOS Migration Assistant transfer *everything* from one drive to another? Or does it only look at apps, documents and ignores configuration files?

Comment: Did you gave a though to performing a TimeMachine backup and restoring from it on the new Mac? That should be the best approach IMO.

Comment: Actually I heard John Gruber on his podcast remark how surprised he was that Migration Assistant copied all of his command line and PERL configurations to a new Mac, so it may indeed copy all your necessary stuff. That said if you have a *very* specific setup cloning the drive from one to the other or using a 3rd party backup utility that grabs **everything** in the profile might be the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Yea, macOS Migration Assistant ignores configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to copy EVERYTHING will be to clone the drive, as far as I'm aware.  You may be able to use Time Machine if you have a current backup of your "old" Mac, and connect that drive to the new Mac.  Time Machine includes settings.

Answer (score -1):

[Mackup](https://github.com/lra/mackup) is really good as you can get a really recent version of the files configured, and you can easily write your own configuration files to backup other specific files and locations you may want! If you create a brewfile and list of what you’ll need I found it fairly easy to reinstall dotfiles, formulas, apps quickly!

Comment: Looked into migration strategies again and found this question… from myself 3 years ago :) Looks like Mackup is what I was looking for, not sure why you got downvoted like that. Thank you for the recommendation!